# How do I prevent Windows from resetting my default Documents folder to OneDrive?

Tags: dropbox, onedrive, windows

I don't use OneDrive that often. I have changed the default Documents folder save location to Dropbox multiple times, by going to `Desktop\Libraries` right click `Documents`, `Properties` `Dropbox`, `set save location`

It works for a while, say a few months, but then each time I update Windows (or seeming randomly), it resets the default save location to OneDrive. Is there a way to prevent this from reoccurring? I find this very annoying as I often don't find my files.

Answer (score 1):

- You want to go to My Documents
- Right click on Properties
- Move the location of that folder.

[image]

Changing your library links are not the same as changing the location of your